# PHP - use Namespace\{Foo, Bar}?

Tags: php, php-7

When did PHP have this below?

```
use Namespace\{Foo, Bar}
```

I came across this pattern from [the php pleague](http://container.thephpleague.com/3.x/basic-usage/):

```
namespace Acme;

class Foo
{
    /**
     * @type Acme\Bar
     */
    public $bar;

    /**
     * Construct.
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bar $bar
     */
    public function __construct(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    // ...
}
```

And then:

```
<?php

use Acme\{Foo, Bar};
```

Is it valid? If it is, where can study this further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. It was introduced in PHP 7.0. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.group):

> From PHP 7.0 onwards, classes, functions and constants being imported
>   from the same namespace can be grouped together in a single use
>   statement.
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> // Pre PHP 7 code
> use some\namespace\ClassA;
> use some\namespace\ClassB;
> use some\namespace\ClassC as C;
>
> ...
>
> // PHP 7+ code
> use some\namespace\{ClassA, ClassB, ClassC as C};
> use function some\namespace\{fn_a, fn_b, fn_c};
> use const some\namespace\{ConstA, ConstB, ConstC};
> ```

Answer (score 2):

[According to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), it's valid in PHP7 and upwards:

> From PHP 7.0 onwards, classes, functions and constants being imported from the same namespace can be grouped together in a single use statement.

They provide the following example:

```
<?php

// Pre PHP 7 code
use some\namespace\ClassA;
use some\namespace\ClassB;
use some\namespace\ClassC as C;

use function some\namespace\fn_a;
use function some\namespace\fn_b;
use function some\namespace\fn_c;

use const some\namespace\ConstA;
use const some\namespace\ConstB;
use const some\namespace\ConstC;

// PHP 7+ code
use some\namespace\{ClassA, ClassB, ClassC as C};
use function some\namespace\{fn_a, fn_b, fn_c};
use const some\namespace\{ConstA, ConstB, ConstC};
```